# How to login into facebook using goutte in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, goutte

I want to login into Facebook using goutte in laravel.
Their is document to login into github but I want to login into facebook and get all the name of person available on the page.
What I am trying

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Log In')->form();

    $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'fabpot', 'pass' => 'xxxxxx'));
    // submit that form
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
    echo $crawler->html();

    return $this->render('scraperBundle:Thing:index.html.twig');
```

But I am getting error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Crawler.php line 822:
The current node list is empty.
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This is will work

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://en-gb.facebook.com/login/');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Log In')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'email', 'pass' => 'pass'));
$crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
echo $crawler->html();
```